# window.open('my-app://', '_blank'); does not launch desktop app from the browser, but going to my-app:// in the browser does

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I open Chrome and type in `my-app://` in the URL / search bar, and press enter, Chrome displays a dialog box that says "Open my-app? A website wants to open this application". I can click ok and my Electron app opens.

I have a React app and I want to add the same functionality, that programatically prompts the user to launch the application via an alert. I have tried adding `window.open('my-app://', '_blank')` which opens a dialog, but it is not the same as the other dialog and when I click ok, I am told by Chrome that is has blocked a pop-up, and the app does not open. I have also tried using `window.location.href = 'my-app://'`, but it does not work. In the console I get the error: "Failed to launch 'my-app://' because the scheme does not have a registered handler."

How do I present the user with a prompt / alert that when ok is clicked will launch my app, just like it does when I enter my-app:// manually in to the browser?

Comment: you missing some quotes in the second one?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out - it was a typo in the question.

Comment: You could try making it as an anchor element and see if that works when clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `document.location`, this works for opening VS Code.

```js
function openVSC() {
  document.location = 'vscode://open?url=';
}
```

```html
<button onClick="openVSC()">Open VS Code</button>
```